# use rgba(var --color, .8) in sass doesn't work

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

```css
 scss.js

// theme color
$themeColor: var(--color_theme, #409EFF);

// el-table reset
$table_th: rgba($themeColor, 0.8);
```

Seen on Chrome element is colorless

[image]

Comment: @toyotaSupra ??

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
$theme-color: #409EFF !default;
```

and then call it

```
body {
  background: $theme-color;
}
```